# Selecting only if at least one row matches condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select statement and want to return all values only if at least one of them has a date with 60 days of difference from today.
The problem is that i have an outer apply which returns the column i want to compare to, and they come from different tables (one belongs to cash items, and the other to card items).
Considering I have the following:

```
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS quantity, MIN(date) AS item_date
        FROM dbo.get_cash_items(loans.id_cash) AS cash_item
        HAVING loans.id_product_type = 1 --Cash
    UNION
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS quantity, MIN(date) AS item_date
        FROM dbo.get_card_items(loans.id_card) AS card_item
        HAVING loans.id_product_type = 2 --Card
) AS items
```

I want to return all the rows only when `DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(items.item_date), GETDATE()) >= 60`, but I want them all even if only one matches this condition.
What would be the best approach to do this?

**EDIT**
To make it clearer, I'll explain the use case:
I need to show the items of every loan, only if the client is late for more than 60 days of the due date on any of it

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using `UNION` and not `UNION ALL`?

Comment: It is the same, I will be getting the items according to the loans.id_product_type, and it's always going to be either one or the other (no union really happen).

Comment: I see. I would **strongly** recommend you always use `UNION ALL` unless you need to remove duplicates. It is much faster as the engine skips the extra step of checking for duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also not sure, what do you expect, but how about that:

```
WITH items
     AS (SELECT Count(*)  AS quantity,
                Min(date) AS item_date
         FROM   dbo.Get_cash_items(loans.id_cash) AS cash_item
         HAVING loans.id_product_type = 1
         UNION
         SELECT Count(*)  AS quantity,
                Min(date) AS item_date
         FROM   dbo.Get_card_items(loans.id_card) AS card_item
         HAVING loans.id_product_type = 2)
SELECT a.*
FROM   items AS a,
       (SELECT TOP 1 *
        FROM   items AS b
        WHERE  Datediff(day, b.item_date, Getdate()) >= 60) AS c
```

It's a sort of CROSS JOIN, where table `C` will have one or zero rows depending on that if the condition is met - it will than join to every row in other table.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
SELECT a.quantity, a.item_date
FROM
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS quantity, MIN(date) AS item_date
        FROM dbo.get_cash_items(loans.id_cash) AS cash_item
        HAVING loans.id_product_type = 1
    UNION
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS quantity, MIN(date) AS item_date
        FROM dbo.get_card_items(loans.id_card) AS card_item
        HAVING loans.id_product_type = 2) a 
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, a.item_date, GETDATE()) >= 60
```

Comment: This is only going to return the rows which match the condition.

Comment: @PabloMartínez Could you please show us some sample data with the desired result?

Comment: I edited my answer. If one row matches the condition I wrote, I need to get all the rows, otherwise none of them.

Comment: @PabloMartínez What's the qualifier for matching? More specifically, if there is matched rows, what attributes are supposed to be used to fetch all of them?

Comment: Imagine it is exactly what you wrote, but I want all the rows when any of them matches (if i had one row having 60 days of diff between its date and today, bring all the rows even when not all of them match it)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the solution posted by @WojtusJ explains what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Typically I do this using a CTE to select the key for the records I want to select and then join on that.  Below is an attempt at an example:

```
with LateClients as
(
    SELECT LoadId FROM Payment Where /*payment date later than 60 days*/
)

SELECT     p.LoanId, 
           p.UserId 
FROM       Payment as p
INNER JOIN LateClients as LC
ON         p.LoanId = lc.LoanId 
OrderBy    p.LoanId, p.UserId
```

I know it's a bit different from the code you posted, but this is a simplified example that should explain the concept.  Good luck!

Comment: This would bring only payments with date later than 60 days, and I want all payments even if only one of them is that late. Solution by @WojtusJ does this.

Comment: I don't know how your tables are structures so I can't say if that is true or not.  What I can say is that if your payments table has a LoanId column, the query above will bring all payments for a specific loan if that loan has any payments that are later than 60 days.  It WILL NOT only select late payments.